# Wrong ouput when all cases are input together while correct when put individually

Tags: java

I was trying Codeforces problem 1921-C. Problem is when I put a single test case it works fine but with if I put all the test cases together the result changes.

For the test case

```
12 621526648 2585904 3566299
51789 61859 71998 73401 247675 298086 606959 663464 735972 806043 806459 919683
```

the ouput should be "Yes" but when multiple inputs including this are given together it shows "No".

My code is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int test = sc.nextInt();

        for (int t_ = 0; t_ < test; t_++) {
            long n = sc.nextLong();
            long f = sc.nextLong();
            long a = sc.nextLong();
            long b = sc.nextLong();
            long now = 0L;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                long m = sc.nextLong();
                long min = Math.min(a*(m - now), b);
                f = f - min;
                if(f <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("No");
                    break;
                }
                now = m;
            }
            if(f > 0) {
                System.out.println("Yes");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you should prefer `BufferedReader` over `Scanner` to avoid exceeding the time limit on problems with a large amount of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error doesn't actually occur in this test case, but in the test case right before it (in the example inputs listed on the [problem page](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1921/C)). It's this error that causes your program to misinterpret the last test case and give the wrong answer as a side-effect.

The issue is with this part of the code:

```
if(f <= 0) {
    System.out.println("No");
    break;
}
```

What's the problem? The problem is that if we print "No" and break the loop, and you're not on the last data point of the test case, your code will *forget to read the rest of the test case*.

In the example inputs on the problem page, the result of the second-to-last test case becomes apparent after reading two of the three data points. This means that you don't read the last data point, 10, as a data point, but as the length of the next test case. The real length, 12, gets read as the value for `f`, and so on, with the entire test case getting misaligned and giving the wrong result.

Comment: Yeah, just used sc.nextLine() before break. Thanks